# Why in Google Play 10.3.12 I have old layout?

Tags: google-play-store

I have `Google Play 10.3.12-all [0] [PR] 198814133` on Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 (with MIUI 9.5) and earlier I had the new layout of Store, but now I see that the old one came back.

Is this related to uncertified/rooted device?

I searched internet but I didn't find any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling Google play services?

https://www.google.dk/amp/s/www.androidpit.com/install-google-play-services-apk%3famp=true

Although I would like to point out that sometimes Google play store indeed does change some functions. Sometimes I see the downloads as text, sometimes I see it as an icon.

Comment: I reinstalled Google Play Services and Google Play Store, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Google is very fond of doing server-side switches and a slow rollout to measure the reactions of people to redesigns. It does not have anything to do with being rooted or having your bootloader unlocked.

I'm thinking that it's just based on probability - between ROM flashes on my devices, one of them will occasionally get the new Play Store UI. Don't sweat it.

If you liked the new layout, there's nothing you can do to get it back except to wait for the inevitable wider rollout.